# How to setup CDN for my mobile website only?

Tags: cdn, cname

I've purchased the CDN for my mobile website.
Suppose I run my website at `domain m.example.com`.
Then what will be the primary domain name that will be cached?

Please suggest full process to setup CDN with my mobile website (`m.example.com`) not desktop site (`www.example.com`)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed setup CDN to serve only m.example.com. Full detailed process depends on CDN provider you will choose.

Comment: After more google search i found That i need to provide domain name to service provider that will be cached in CDN server. And I need to access that cached static content form CND aliases.